# Users are not able to follow documents in my SP2013 site, what should I do?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, following

The site that I have has the feature of "Following Content" activated, but users can't follow any of the documents in it. Can someone help me here? What else do I have to do to completely activate this feature?

The following message appears when I try to follow a document:
[image: The following message appears when I try to follow a document]

After hitting Get Started in the first window the page redirects me to my profile. And then nothing happens:
[image: After hitting Get Started on the first window, the page redirects me to my profile. And then nothing happens]

Comment: It seems User Profile Service is not setup properly.

Comment: How and what do I need to set in the User Profile Service?

Comment: check this one: http://kx.cloudingenium.com/microsoft/servers/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/how-to-resolve-issue-microsoft-office-server-userprofiles-personalsitecreateexception-a-failure-was-encountered-while-attempting-to-create-the-site-while-using-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: That didn't solved the problem. I did a full crawl just to be sure that changes where done.